# Unattended installation prompting for password

Tags: oem, kickstart

I'll start by posting this question here, and expand to other exchanges if the response rate is low.  But I think the excellent Ubuntu community is the right place to begin.

I am trying to accomplish an unattended installation of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS using the minimal ISO net installer.  I am orchestrating this installation with Hashicorp packer.

I have followed all guides, tips, tricks and setup techniques to great success. However, I am at a stuck place, so I am asking here for how to get beyond this very annoying issue I am having.

TL;DR: The installation is stopping and asking for a password.

The boot line I am using is:

```
linux initrd=initrd.gz file=/floppy/preseed.cfg priority=critical \
auto-install/enable=true oem-config/enable=true  \
debian-installer/locale=en_US netcfg/choose_interface=auto  \
quiet splash noprompt noshell  \
--
```

Maybe I've got extra useless stuff here, I am not 100% on this line.

Then the relevant sections of the kickstart preseed which should have (I thought) gotten me over the hump of the user/password dialogs.

```
# Users
# Root password, either in clear text
d-i passwd/root-login boolean true
d-i passwd/root-password-crypted password $6$mz7Yiq85Dk3uVc$L9D5BHr8QbC4PM/.5iq5kloKRxN4uRMmIyWanNFCTkuWGBEVFBC.sU.1ulfXdIh3amUdvnwY/PJ5FSDI.qxYQ0
# non root user
d-i passwd/user-fullname string ubuntu
d-i passwd/username string ubuntu
d-i passwd/user-password-crypted password $6$aEVY19fh9gXxlnD$rwfMtBhQLkTAz5wJzfJZtsNvIx1Sop1kFFpDzmffhcgXwVexJRzclQXZB5pw4.UqUhy3SvwX98zqyugiqWPJA0
d-i passwd/user-default-groups string wheel adm sudo
d-i user-setup/allow-password-weak boolean true
```

What obvious mistakes have I made here?
What not-so-obvious assumptions might I have made which are causing a failure for me?